# How to program a InProcServer32 .dll file in VB.NET

Tags: windows, vb.net, explorer

I'm trying to create my own "InProcServer32" .dll file with the help of Visual Basic. This process caught my attention when I came across on of the features from iCloud. The "iCloud Photos" that's displayed on "My Computer"(also known as "This PC" today).When Opened, it displays 2 files or button like items on folder view which are download and upload photos, I know that the iCloud's "ShellStreams" .dll file is responsible for this used in InProcServer32 that uses "IShellFolder" programmed from C or C++. But what I want is to trigger something instead of using "IShellFolder" or not to do "Shell Namespace Extension", like displaying a message box. Is it possible to execute this type of trigger in VB.NET without needing C or C++?

Comment: Project > Properties > Application tab > Assembly Information button > tick the "Make assembly COM-visible" checkbox.

Comment: Ok, I know that I have to make COM visible, but how do you tell regedit which code (eg: Sub Main(), Private Sub [SubName], Public Sub[SubName], etc...) to execute

Comment: Not the way it works, at all.  You have not thought sufficiently about the way you are going to activate the code you wrote.  When you write a shell namespace extension then it will be Explorer that does it, but all we know is that it is not what you want to do.  COM allows your library to be used by just about any language, but if you don't have one in mind then it is not useful.

Comment: No, I want "Explorer" to execute my program, what I meant was that I don't know how to tell Explorer to execute a code I wrote, like I said before, displaying a message box[ MsgBox("You opened a folder!") ]

Comment: Extension points for Explorer are limited, you are hoping for a feature that doesn't exist.  Other than a namespace extension.  Google ".net shell extensions" for hits.  The "don't do it" warnings you'll see are real btw.

Comment: So is it possible? If so, thank you.